# algorithm search close tag

Tags: algorithm

[Image http://img534.imageshack.us/img534/8542/aaagla.jpg](http://img534.imageshack.us/img534/8542/aaagla.jpg)
It is good to give me a example (any language)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pseudocode

```
input:  lineopen  (line having opening tag)
input:  text      (test as array of lines)
output: lineclose (line having closing tag)

line := lineopen
counter := 1
do
    line := line + 1
    if text[line] contains opening tag
        then counter := counter + 1
    if text[line] contains closing tag
        then counter := counter - 1
while counter > 0
lineclose := line
```

Answer (score 3):

The traditional way to do this is with a stack. Push when you get an open tag, and pull when you get a close tag. Pulling from an empty stack or having a non-zero stack at the end indicates mismatched tags.

Comment: Simple inclusion counter (increase it on opening tag, decrease on closing) would be enough until author wants check tag parity.